# SQL CASE WHEN customer's sponsor's last month's rank was 6, then double the quantity

Tags: sql, subquery, case

Criteria needed: when the customer's sponsor had a rank of 6 last month, then double the quantity.

I'm expecting the code to look like this:
Select customerID, orderID, sponsorID, LastMonthRank,
CASE WHEN **SponsorIDLastMonthRank** = 6 then Qty * 2 else Qty end as Qty

The problem is I don't have a field called SponsorIdLastMonthRank, but I do have SponsorID & LastMonthRank fields.

SponsorID is the CustomerID's sponsor, essentially.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3YxO.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYsQw.png)

Comment: Please add Table structure, Sample data and expected data, which will help to get more clarity for your question

Comment: Okay, I have added my table structure and my expected results!

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you just do CASE WHEN LastMonthRank - You don't need SponserId at all here.